# Android from (HTTP) POST to GET

Tags: php, android, http-post, http-get

I am working on 2 the same apps that need to send to an php file the same string. The iOs one is a GET when i use this code in PHP to check it.

```
file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" . print_r($_GET, true));
```

But the Android one is a POST, but they need to be exactely the same, because i already build an working part of PHP that i cant change anymore.

Here's my android code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://Myserver.com/default.php");

            json = new JSONObject(); 
            try { 
                json.put("id", "69403"); 
                json.put("longitude", longi); 
                json.put("latitude", lat); 
                json.put("timestamp", time); 

            } catch (JSONException e) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

            /// create StringEntity with current json obejct 

            try { 
          //  StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 

                List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json.toString()));
                httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));


                System.out.println("send about to do post");
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("send post done");
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
```

Comment: Then why are you not trying HttpGet in Android?

Comment: Is changing that just enough? because i already tried it but it crashed

Comment: Look at http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/ and http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/ for HttpGet. And if it crashes then you have to post on crashes..

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://Myserver.com/default.php");
```

To

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://Myserver.com/default.php");
```

Comment: When i change this i get an error on this:           httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
 and it want to change it to           ((HttpResponse) httpost).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

but then it crashes

Comment: Can you be more clear, because what is the error message you see?

Comment: Error on setEntity. possible solutions: add cast to httppost. And then it thanges to ((HttpResponse) httpost).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

Comment: That's because HttpGet don't have a setEntity method. And you can't simply replace HttpPost with HttpGet and expect everything to work.

Also from what I know, you can't send any content in the request body using get.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're getting the [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), it's because you're trying to do network operations from the main thread. If so, try looking into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Also make sure that you got internet permission in the android manifest.